# Newbie regex question - detect spam

Tags: regex, detect, spam

Here's my regex newbie questions:

- How can I check if a string has 3 spam words? (for example: viagra, pills and shop)
- How can I detect also variations of those spam words like "v-iagra" or "v.iagra" ? (one additional character)

Comment: http://spamassassin.apache.org

Comment: http://spamassassin.apache.org/tests_3_2_x.html

Answer (score 3):

Regex doesn't seem like quite the right hammer for this particular nail.  For your list, you can simply throw all of you blacklisted words in a sorted list of some kind, and scan each token against that list.  Direct string operations are always faster than invoking the regular expression engine du jour.

For your variations ("v-iagra", et. al) I'd remove all non-characters (as @Kinopiko suggested) and then run them past your blacklist again.  If you're wary of things like "viiagra", et cetera, I'd check out [Aspell](http://aspell.net/).  It's a great library, and looks like CPAN has a Perl binding.

Comment: what about substitutions like `\/iagra`

Comment: Locks only keep honest men honest. If someone is really dedicated, they're going to find a way to write what they want to write. That said, for something like `\/` for a `V`, it seems like the easiest (read: most straightforward) method would need to compile a list of those types of transformations manually, store them in a map (of entries like `["\/" -> "V"]`, and then run a rote string replace from each element of that map on every incoming token.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I check if a string has 3 spam words? (for example: viagra,pills and shop)

A regex to spot any one of those three words might look like this (Perl):

```
if ($string =~ /(viagra|pills|shop)/) {
    # spam
}
```

If you want to spot all three, a regex alone isn't really enough:

```
my $bad_words = 0;
while ($string =~ /(viagra|pills|shop)/g) {
     $bad_words++;
}
if ($bad_words >= 3) {
     # spam
}
```

> How can I detect also variations of those spam words like "v-iagra" or "v.iagra" ? (one additional character)

It's not so easy to do that with just a regex. You could try something like

```
 $string =~ s/\W//g;
```

to remove all non-word characters like . and -, and then check the string using the test above. This would strip spaces too though.

Comment: Don't forget \W includes underscores. Vi_agra would still get through.